# Vim: jump beginning or end of the system verilog module?

Tags: vim, verilog, system-verilog

Is there a way in vim to jump beginning or end of the system verilog module while you are editing ports in middle of it?

E.g. while editing C file you can jump start of the function using `[m`.

EDIT: Maybe I should have defined my question better, but I originally meant that while you are inside module instantiation and one would like to jump beginning or end of the instantiated module.

```
component instance_name (
  .clk (clk),
  .rst (rst),
  .data_i (data_in), 
  .data_o (data_out)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`[m` and `]m` work with braces. But you can redefine them to match your syntax. Something like that:

```
augroup verilog_maps | au!
    autocmd FileType verilog nnoremap <buffer><silent>[m ?^\s*module\><CR>
    autocmd FileType verilog nnoremap <buffer><silent>]m /^\s*module\><CR>
    autocmd FileType verilog nnoremap <buffer><silent>[M ?^\s*endmodule\><CR>
    autocmd FileType verilog nnoremap <buffer><silent>]M /^\s*endmodule\><CR>
augroup END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my initial thought was that while you are inside an module  instantiation. Maybe I should have defined my question better.

Comment: I would recommend using `search()` over `/` or `?` to not pollute the search register.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a vim plugin like this. You can refer my script to implement your requirement.

```
https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5980
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).